# Reducer in react-redux-toolkit not update state

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

My reducer `removeMovie` is not working. Every time I get all initial data from state without one element. I need to update state on every call.

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import movies from '../../services/movies.json';

export const movieSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'movie',
  initialState: movies,
  reducers: {
    addMovie: (state, action) => {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    removeMovie: (state, action) => {
      state = state.filter(movie => movie.title !== action.payload);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
    },
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { addMovie, removeMovie } = movieSlice.actions;

export default movieSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing in removeMovie reducer is not tracked by Immer library. With this line `state = state.filter(movie => movie.title !== action.payload);` you are assigning local state variable, and that is not actually change of state. You can try this:

```
removeMovie: (state, action) => {
  const newState = state.filter(movie => movie.title !== action.payload);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(newState));
  return newState;
},
```

You can find more about this on the following link: [immer usage patterns](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#immer-usage-patterns)

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. Thank you.